# Suitable replacement for SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (SQL Server 2012 )

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm currently looking for a replacement for Latin1_General_CI_AS as I need to differentate between
ß and ss and I found SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. The problem with this collation though is
that it is merely a legacy collation and thus should be avoided if possible.

Now my question is is there another collation which provides the same functionalities as the legacy one?

Edit:
As an info here I need to have the collation be case insensitive as I run into troubles else with the where statements. Additionally as I'm using C#'s entity framework to gather the data I need to avoid possibilities that would result in special where statements (such as using convert in the where statement)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from where convert(varbinary,word)=convert(varbinary,'search')
```

or

```
Select * from where convert(varbinary,upper(word))= convert(varbinary,upper('search'))
```

or

```
Select * from where convert(varbinary,lower(word))= convert(varbinary,lower('search'))
```

Comment: Place your own columns or text and check it will work

Comment: Hmmm, partially working, but a (probably not desired) side effect of this is that you lose also case insensitivity... (so `SS` is not equal to `ss`)

Comment: then have a case statement when only alphabets normal when special characters try this...

Comment: Check now and let me know

Comment: Sadly not really what I'm looking for (I'm filling an autocompletebox in C# with the data where I need to be case insensitive and use a like statement (using entityframework to be exact)) so a conversion in the where part is sadly not really what I'm looking for (at least if there is any other possibility)

Comment: @ThomasE. With an EntityFramework context, I guess you have no other choice than using the collation you found. Didn't find any alternative one...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I feared just that (I didnt find anything myself but hoped I had overlooked something there).